# Why does chrome close a window opened from a non-script with window.close()?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I don't think it did not close before.

This is the result of testing with the attached html.

> Close. chrome 107.0.5304.89(Official Build)
> Close. Edge 107.0.1418.35 (Official Build)(64bit)
> Not close. Firefox 106.0.5(64bit)

This document says it will not be closed.
[Window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    window.close();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked some Chromium issue threads, and it seems that Chromium browsers follow different logic from Firefox.

**In short**, if a tab has only 1 item in backward/forward history, `window.close()` works and closes the tab. But it is not counted as an issue, partly because they think

> This is a useful option for automated testing.  It allows you to set
> up test pages that clean up themselves when they're done.

Reference link:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22070
https://codereview.chromium.org/22929032/#ps9001

Comment: I understand. If the tab back button is disabled, you can close it with window.close().